# vscode vim vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

When I try to re-bind the vim shortcut with the following configuration, it doesn't take effect.

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["<S-h>"],
            "after": ["^"]
        },{
            "before": ["<S-l>"],
            "after": ["g", "_"]
        }
 ]
```

> what should I do?

Comment: what should `<S-h>` be? Shift? Than it would be `H`

Comment: I am very sorry, I have a bad question, but it does bother me.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. If you try to map `Shift+h` you should write `"before": ["H"]` and not `<S-h>`

Comment: Thank you very much, solved my troubles.

Comment: I can understand what you mean, I am sorry for my silly.

Comment: No need to be sorry, don't worry